How can I generate an add to google calendar link using ReactJS?
How can I generate an add to google calendar link using react JS? I found online that the link is
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Example+Google+Calendar+Event&details=More+help+see:+https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/81344786&dates=20201231T160000/20201231T170000&recur=RRULE:FREQ%3DWEEKLY;UNTIL%3D20210603&ctz=America/Toronto 

but I don't know how to generate the dates for the link in javascript or the parameters. like recur?

Not enough information, please add what you exactly need.
